# Is this a safe way to set values in a DataFrame? Why does this work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm using `.loc` to filter my DataFrame and set values from another column. Here's a short example, first setting up a simple DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Steve', 'Julie', 'Dan', 'Mary'],
    'nickname': ['Steve-o', 'Jules', '', '']
})

#     name  nickname
# 0  Steve   Steve-o
# 1  Julie     Jules
# 2    Dan         
# 3   Mary
```

Next I replace the missing values using `.loc` like this:

```py
df.loc[df['nickname'] == '', 'nickname'] = df['name']

#     name  nickname
# 0  Steve   Steve-o
# 1  Julie     Jules
# 2    Dan       Dan
# 3   Mary      Mary
```

Why does this even work? I'm assigning a series of a different length, how does it know to only match the items with the same index number? Why doesn't it throw an error about the series being different lengths? This just seems very magical to me and it makes me nervous.

After lots of searching, I can't find any examples of this approach in the official documentation. I have seen a few rare examples of this out in the wild, but with no explanation or reassurance that it's a correct approach.

Comment: pandas aligns everything based on the index, before doing any computation. that's a fundamental approach of the library. so your code above makes sense. You can give it a try and flip the indices of `df[name]` when reassigning. if none of the indices match, then it should raise an error. Of course, you can disable index alignment by passing an array instead

Comment: I tried to recreate this behavior by working with two Series objects, but when I tried to do an assignment using a slice or something, I get an error about them being different lengths. So I guess I was just having a hard time understanding how when I use `.loc` suddenly that no longer is an issue. Thank you for the reassurance though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Pandas sets the values by the corresponding index. The index of the `name` is `0` `1` `2` `3`, but the located rows (`loc`) indexes are `2` and `3`, so it would reindex the original `name` column to only the `2` and `3` index.

Here is a proof:

If we were to assign to a completely different index:

```
>>> df['name'].set_axis(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
a    Steve
b    Julie
c      Dan
d     Mary
Name: name, dtype: object
>>>
```

It wouldn't work, example:

```
>>> df.loc[df['nickname'] == '', 'nickname'] = df['name'].set_axis(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> df
    name nickname
0  Steve  Steve-o
1  Julie    Jules
2    Dan      NaN
3   Mary      NaN
>>>
```

There is the proof! `loc` assignment is based on row indexes, in this case None of the indexes matched, so it gave missing values (`NaN`).

If you use a list or array which doesn't have indexes, this wouldn't work.

This is the *"magic"* of Pandas.

**Do not think that indexes are nothing, Pandas assigns everything based on the indexes.**

---

Performance-wise I prefer to use:

```
df.loc[df['nickname'] == '', 'nickname'] = df.loc[df['nickname'] == '', 'name']
```

To make Pandas not need to do the extra work of matching the indexes.

For some cases with big `DataFrame`s:

```
df.loc[df['nickname'] == '', 'nickname'] = df['name']
```

Would give an `MemoryError`, but:

```
df.loc[df['nickname'] == '', 'nickname'] = df.loc[df['nickname'] == '', 'name']
```

Wouldn't, because the number of rows of the assignment are less.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was considering using the example you gave where you're using `.iloc` on both sides of the assignment, as I felt more comfortable with that since it is so explicit about what it is doing.

Comment: @Glenn Yeah! Pandas is magical :)